# Google-VR SDK: Unity gvraudiolistener script and world scale

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

I'm working on a frogger google cardboard vr game where I have a river and the river plays a "waves" audio clip. Once I scale my game world up 100x, the clip is faint. I can hear the sound play but in a very small radius. Even If I turn the Global Gain (db) in my gvraudiolistener script all the way up, I can only hear the waves play in a very small radius. I increased Volume Rollof: Min Distance to 1000 and Max Distance to 50000, and max out Gain (db) in my gvraudiosource script but the small radius is still an issue. How do I go about accounting for my world scale change with my gvraudiolistener script?

In the tutorial I'm following, the sound issue was maxing out a World Scale property. world scale property pic
However, it would appear the latest sdk does not have this world scale property anymore Anyone know how I may get my sound working correctly to account for world upscaling?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FyM2.jpg)

vs

[my listener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3KkS.jpg)

Update** World Scale property was removed between v0.6 and v1.0 of Google Cardboard SDK update. How do I go about achieving the same effect?

Comment: There was a change in google cardboard sdk between v0.6 and v1.0.  Hmm anyone know how to resolve this sound issue without downgrading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an official answer from the gvr sdk team

> Hi, we removed the world scale parameter to be able to integrate Unity's internal distance attenuation calculation into our Unity plugin. To fix this, you'll need to rescale your environment to match 1 unit = 1 meter.